# Is there a way of testing a method's ability to handle concurrent calls?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a method which creates an entity in a database table. I want to test the scenario where the method gets invoked twice at the exact same time.

The method has logic to avoid such a scenario and fail one of the 2 requests but I have no way to confirm if that is working correctly.

Is there a way to test this without the test being flaky?

I crudely tried invoking the action simultaneously from 2 browsers but they don't execute in parallel. I suppose that will take a lot of trial and error to get them execute at the exact same time (it's an war file running on tomcat)

Comment: Why aren't you just using standard transactions?

Comment: @chrylis Can you elaborate please? Are you talking about hibernate transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem. Here is the exact code I wrote to tackle that particular problem:

```
  @Test
  public void mapVertexToLazyObjectWithSameMapperOnMultipleThreadsAtTheSameTime()  {
    StackVertex vertex = new StackVertex(graph, 1L, "test", Optional.empty());
    mockVertex(vertex, NO_EDGES, NO_EDGES, properties("name", "foobar"));

    VertexEntityMapper<NamedNode> mapper = objectMapper.getMapper(NamedNode.class);
    NamedNode obj = mapper.mapToObject(vertex);

    final Boolean[] flags = { false, false };
    Runnable run = () -> {
      if ( obj.getName() == null || !obj.getName().equals("foobar") ) {
        flags[0]  = true;
      }
    };

    List<Thread> threads = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed()
      .map(i -> new Thread(run)).collect(toList());
    threads.forEach(Thread::start);
    threads.forEach((thread) -> {
      try { thread.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        flags[1] = true;
      }
    });

    verify(vertexRepository, times(1)).findById(graph.tx(), 1L, Optional.empty());
    assertFalse("race condition",     flags[0]);
    assertFalse("thread interrupted", flags[1]);
  }
```

It's pretty simple, but works perfectly. If I made the code thread unsafe this test easily found an issue with it. I played around with the number of threads a bit, but found that with 10 threads I could always reproduce race conditions or exceptions thrown by thread unsafety.

Comment: Thanks Lodewijk, this is pretty cool! I will give it an attempt.

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily elaborate way of saying "call the method from a bunch of simultaneous threads," which is not reliable unless the code being tested is known to contain a delay (and even then, it's still not reliable).  The fact that it "seems to work" doesn't mean it's reliable.  It relies on the code never finishing before all the threads have started up and attempted to make their simultaneous calls.

Comment: @VGR I thought I'd give a different answer for once. You may answer in your way if you feel like it. Furthermore I tested this in a loop hundreds of times; each time it would find my issue if I made the code thread unsafe. That may not be proof, but it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

Test the test.

Take a copy of the method that should be thread-safe, and make the copy thread-unsafe. Write a unit-test that fires up a dozen threads with a runnable that:

1) Has a shared [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

2) Waits on the CountDownLatch to reach zero.

3) Calls the thread-unsafe method.

With the CountDownLatch you can trigger all threads to call the thread-unsafe method at more or less the same time (all threads are ready to go from the same point in the runnable when the CountDownLatch reaches zero, but ultimately it is up to your operating system (and hardware) to decide what gets executed when).
Evaluate the results: you should now see a discrepancy (e.g. 11 records inserted instead of the 12 you expected).

Repeat the test or put your test in a for-loop (and replace the CountDownLatch with a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), another concurrent tool that comes in handy for these kind of tests). In any case, make sure your test always shows the undesired result (e.g. never assume threads start at the same time, synchronize them with tools like a CountDownLatch so you know exactly where threads are).

Replace the call to the thread-unsafe method with a call to the thread-safe method in the unit test. You should now see the desired and expected results without a discrepancy.

I have not given much detail here, but there is also not much detail in the question. In any case, the general idea is to first setup a situation where it should go wrong and use automated brute force (many threads calling the method many times in a loop) combined with the smart use of concurrent tools like the CountDownLatch to show the test will always bring certain issues to the surface. The "smart use of concurrent tools" will take some time, insight and practice (e.g. it took me some time to figure out that after calling "thread.start()" the thread might not have started yet and that a CountDownLatch could be used to make sure the thread is where I want it to be).

Disclaimer: these kind of "tested" tests will not catch all concurrency issues (you only test what you think can fail and there are also other problems like for example broken [Double checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)), but they will harden your code and bring likely concurrency issues to surface.

Comment: Thank you, the CountDownLatch idea is handy.